# Windows Server 2008 R2 RDP Printers Not Mapping

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-services

Having an issue with one user's printers not mapping when connecting via RDP to a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit with Terminal Services. Here's the scenario:

- Approximately 7 users connect via RDP to a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit server running Terminal Services
- Users connect via either Windows 7 or Windows XP SP3 workstations running latest RDP client
- All users connect via the same Organizational Unit and utilize the same Group Policy
- Users have 3 networked printers that their RDP client is setup to map:

  - HP LaserJet 4250 PCL 6 (Default)
  - HP LaserJet P4010_P4510 PCL 6
  - Sharp MX-5001N PCL6
- 6 of the 7 users have all their printers successfully mapped
- The user that is not successful does not have any printers being mapped. As a troubleshooting step, we setup a Generic/Text Only and verified that that printer was mapped.
- Have installed printer drivers for the above listed printers directly on the Terminal Server

Not sure what steps to take at this point -- any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Stupid question, but have you checked the Local Resources under the RDP Options that Printers is selected?

Comment: Yep that's checked from the client end and is configured via the GPO. We were thinking that maybe something was going on from that end, but when we setup the Generic/Text Only printer and verified that it mapped, that issue was ruled out.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/common-windows-issues-mapped-printers-unreachable

Ensure that the Terminal Services Configuration (2003 R2 and 2008) and the Remote Desktop Services Configuration (2008 R2) allows for client printer mapping.

**For Windows 2008:**  Click Start, Administrative Tools, Terminal Services, Terminal Services Configuration.  On the left pane, select RD Session Host Configuration and then right-click RDP-Tcp within the Connections section of the right-hand pane, then select Properties.  In the window that pops up, click the Client Settings tab and make sure that the box next to Windows Printer is UNCHECKED (read: a check in this box means printer mapping is DISABLED).

**For Windows 2008 R2:**  Click Start, Administrative Tools, Remote Desktop Services, Remote Desktop Host Configuration. On the left pane, select RD Session Host Configuration and then right-click RDP-Tcp within the Connections section of the right-hand pane, then select Properties.  In the window that pops up, click the Client Settings tab and make sure that the box next to Windows Printer is UNCHECKED (read: a check in this box means printer mapping is DISABLED).

**For Windows 2003 R2:** Click Start, Administrative Tools, Terminal Services Configuration. Select the Connections folder and right-click RDP-Tcp and select Properties.  In the window that pops up, click the Client Settings tab and make sure that the box next to Windows Printer Mapping is UNCHECKED (read: a check in this box means printer mapping is DISABLED).  Note:  Rackspace no longer offers Cloud Servers with Windows 2003, but these instructions are here for legacy support purposes.

EDIT - I found my issue:
Check your EVENT VIEWER - SYSTEM
*"Driver TOSHIBA Universal Printer required for printer !!cgy-dc1!Spa-Colour is unknown. Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again."*